# Semantic iterator declaration?

Tags: c++, iterator, semantics

I'm sorry for the very vague title, I really didn't know how to title this question.

Let's say I have this:

```
std::list<std::string> msgs;

for (std::list<std::string>::iterator it = msgs.begin(); it < msgs.end(); it++) {
    // ...
}
```

For me, this is hard to to read. The `std::list<std::string>::iterator` almost seems like a magic number, especially if the declaration of `msgs` is far away, like in an header file. IMO it would be easier to read and much more semantic if it were something like this:

```
std::list<std::string> msgs;

for (msgs.iterator it = msgs.begin(); it < msgs.end(); it++) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, this is obviously illegal C++. But my question is, is there a way of implementing something that supports writing iterator declarations like this?

Comment: I like this question. Because you're right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you provide a typedef it will make life a lot easier:

```
typedef std::list<std::string>::iterator ListIterator;
for( ListIterator it = msgs.begin(); it != msgs.end(); ++it ){}
```

Other than that, c++0x does it for you by providing the auto keyword:

```
for( auto it = msgs.begin(); it != msgs.end(); ++it ){}
```

*edit* like 5 years after date, but I updated `<` tp `!=` and using preincrement because that's actually what I've been doing for ages, and makes more sense to me, to the point it makes me wonder how I ever wrote this answer not using that

Comment: Yup, those are essentially the two canonical solutions.

Comment: There's nothing canonical about post-incrementing iterators in loop conditions, using `<` instead of `!=` and re-calculating `end()` each time. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @Tomalak could have told the author to just use std::for_each( msgs.begin(), msgs.end(), SomeFunc ); but that doesn't really answer his specific question

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: post-incrementing iterators in loop conditions is fine, re-calculating `end()` is optimized out by any decent compiler and you are right about `<` vs `!=`.

Comment: @nightcracker: I'm not convinced that re-calculating `end()` *can* be optimised out.

Comment: @stijn: Oh, I know.. and I upvoted your answer. But I didn't want Konrad's comment to give the wrong impression.

Comment: Post or pre-incrementation doesn't really make any difference; it's more a question of house style.  But using `<` won't work; for a list iterator, it probably won't even compile.

Answer (score 4):

There are two practical, canonical approaches:

```
typedef std::list<int> list_t;
list_t l;

// later:
for (list_t::iterator it = l.begin(), end = l.end(); it != end; ++it) {}
```

And the C++0x-only `auto`:

```
std::list<int> l;

// later:
for (auto it = l.begin(), end = l.end(); it != end; ++it) {}
```

In addition, C++0x allows:

```
std::list<int> l;

// later:
for (decltype(l)::iterator it = l.begin(), end = l.end(); it != end; ++it)
   std::cout << *it << ", ";
```

I think that this is the closest match to what you were *specifically* asking (even if it's not necessarily the best solution).

The downside is that the ability to apply the scope operator (`::`) to `decltype` <sup>[link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3031.pdf)</sup> was only voted into the working paper relatively recently, and I'm not aware of any compilers that support it yet (GCC 4.5.1 [does not](http://www.ideone.com/JRZuS)).

Comment: If its `C++0x`, then why not use `auto` instead?

Comment: +1. This is interesting and more verbose than auto, which although very nice, sometimes feel like total abuse.

Comment: @Nawaz: Some people (myself included) find `auto` a bit too snaky. You never know what you're getting! This method is simple, but _precise_. C++ is not PHP. :P

Comment: On the plus side, the `auto` solution is obviously correct. Consider this "snaky" variant: `for (decltype(l)::iterator it = l.rbegin(), end = l.rend();...`. The whole point of `auto` is to stop playing the "guess what type I'm thinking of" game with the compiler, and start writing code.

Comment: @MSalters: Nonsense! `auto` is the _definition_ of the "guess what type I'm thinking of" game. And, yes, you'd have to write `::reverse_iterator`; frankly, I _want_ to have to!

Answer (score 1):

You can use typedef to clean that up:

```
typedef std::list<std::string>::iterator string_iterator;

std::list<std::string> msgs;

for (string_iterator it = msgs.begin(); it != msgs.end(); it++) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All containers have these `typedef`s to enable the writing of very generic code. Consider the following function-template:

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T& container) {
    for(T::const_iterator it = T.begin(); it != T.end(); it++) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This enables you to write code that can work with any object that has defines a type `const_iterator` and a method `begin()` and `end()`.

In C++0x the problem is solved with the introduction of the `auto` keyword:

```
for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical solution is

```
std::for_each(msgs.begin(), msgs.end(), ... );
```

Before C++0x, writing the `...` bit used to be a bit hard (if it was anything complex), but we now have lambda's.